# Must I call OpenAI API via a https and live site?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, openai-api

I use WAMP Server to create a local server and install WordPress site at http://127.0.0.2

Then I use a WordPress plugin to call OpenAI API, but get the following error:

“cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for [https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions?my-param=bar”](https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions?my-param=bar%E2%80%9D)

Does that means I must install a SSL on my server and access it via https instead of http to call OpenAI API? Also the developer of the plugin told me that I need to call OpenAI API from a live server instead of a local server, is that the case?

Thanks